# Divert file request to another source controlled server

Tags: svn, apache, .htaccess

We have a flash project which uses XML files for various configurations. I want to put the XML files under source control, so I have setup a SVN server.

On our other staging server, I want to replace any request for .xml files to divert to the SVN server, grab the file from there and send back the result. It'd be useful if I could also include subdirectories too.

http://www.mysite.com/some-project-1/ would get the XML files from http://mysvnserver.com/some-project-1/ for example.

Is this possible to do with htaccess? Would the results from the SVN server come back as XML data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^some-project-1/([a-z0-9-]+)\.xml$ http://your-domain.com/path/$1.xml [P]
```

your apache have to had loaded the mod_proxy module for the P-flag [P]